# The HTML form submits even if the input element is empty

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a HTML form and I use JavaScript to check for empty fields to stop form submission but the form submits to the URL in action attribute even if any one or all fields are empty.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {


        var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
        var lname = document.forms["form1"]["lname"].value;
        var ID = document.forms["form1"]["ID"].value;
        var Password = document.forms["form1"]["Password"].value;

        if(fname == null || lname == null || ID == null || Password == null)
        {
            alert("Please enter all the fields");
            return false;
        };

    }
    </script>

</head>
<body style = "font-family: Lato">

    <div style="padding-left: 10%">
    <h1>Welcome to my site</h1><br>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
       <form  name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()" method = "post" id="form1"  action = "http://127.0.0.1:2906/success" style="padding-top: 2%">
           <label id="user" style="font-size: 20px">Username</label><br>
           <input type="text" name = "ID" placeholder = "Username" style = "padding-left: 0.2%;"><br><br>
           <label style="font-size: 20px">First name</label><br>
           <input type="text" name = "fname" id="fname" placeholder = "First name" style = "padding-left: 0.2%"><br><br>
           <label style="font-size: 20px">Last name</label><br>
           <input type="text" name = "lname" placeholder = "Last name" style = "padding-left: 0.2%"><br><br>
           <label style="font-size: 20px">Password</label><br>
           <input type = "password" name = "Password" placeholder = "Password" style = "padding-left: 0.2%"><br><br><br>
           <input type = "submit"  value = "Sign up" style="width:10%;height: 40px">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `input.value` always returns a string. When a field is not filled out, its value will be the empty string `''`, which is not loosely equal to `null`. Try using `!value` instead, which will work with the empty string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {


        var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
        var lname = document.forms["form1"]["lname"].value;
        var ID = document.forms["form1"]["ID"].value;
        var Password = document.forms["form1"]["Password"].value;

        if(!fname || !lname || !ID || !Password)
        {
            alert("Please enter all the fields");
            return false;
        };

    }
    </script>

</head>
<body style = "font-family: Lato">

    <div style="padding-left: 10%">
    <h1>Welcome to my site</h1><br>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center">
    <form  name="form1" onsubmit="return validate()" method = "post" id="form1"  action = "http://127.0.0.1:2906/success" style="padding-top: 2%">
        <label id="user" style="font-size: 20px">Username</label><br>
        <input type="text" name = "ID" placeholder = "Username" style = "padding-left: 0.2%;"><br><br>
        <label style="font-size: 20px">First name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name = "fname" id="fname" placeholder = "First name" style = "padding-left: 0.2%"><br><br>
        <label style="font-size: 20px">Last name</label><br>
        <input type="text" name = "lname" placeholder = "Last name" style = "padding-left: 0.2%"><br><br>
        <label style="font-size: 20px">Password</label><br>
        <input type = "password" name = "Password" placeholder = "Password" style = "padding-left: 0.2%"><br><br><br>
        <input type = "submit"  value = "Sign up" style="width:10%;height: 40px">
    </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validate() {


        var fname = document.forms["form1"]["fname"].value;
        var lname = document.forms["form1"]["lname"].value;
        var ID = document.forms["form1"]["ID"].value;
        var Password = document.forms["form1"]["Password"].value;

        if(!fname || !lname || !ID || !Password || fname!='' || lname!='' || ID!='' || Password!='')
        {
            alert("Please enter all the fields");
            return false;
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes just simply check for empty string. 
Eg.

```
if($("#elementId").val()==""){
    alert(" please fill username");
    return false;
}
```